# How is current divided in this circuit?

Tags: current-source, current-divider

A homework problem asked to find the current \$I\$(in the middle branch.) Using KVL in the loop on the left, \$I\$ comes out to be \$0A\$, which seem to say that none of the current from the voltage source went into that branch. I'd like to ask why that happens, if that makes sense. Put another way, is there a way to get some intuition as to how current may be divided between branches?

[image: The related electric circuit]

**Working**
In the branch with the \$6\Omega\$ resistance, a current \$(I+4)A\$ flows. using KVL,
$$
24 - 6(I+4)-5I = 0 \\
\rightarrow 24 - 6I -24 -5I = 0 \\
\rightarrow -11I = 0 \\
\rightarrow I = 0
$$
**PS:** *Given in the problem that \$I\$ flows downwards*

Comment: Show us your work; then we can comment on where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: You should have to use KVL in at least two loops here to find I, not just one.

Comment: @Hearth I'm sorry, but I don't see why.......

Comment: @Monochrome Because I is a part of two loops. One of them is trivial because it contains a current source, but you *are* doing two loops' worth of KVL here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'd like to ask why that happens*

It's quite simple really; the 24 volt source and its associated 6 Ω resistor can be Thevenin converted to a current source of 4 amps in parallel with 6 Ω. Given that there is another current source of 4 amps (opposite polarity) it can only mean that there can be no current flowing down the 5 Ω resistor and, as a result, the voltage across that resistor is 0 volts.

[image]